# How to register a function member as callback for boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::async_accept()?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I can register a freestanding function as `async_accept()` callback like so:

```
void accept_cb(const boost::system::error_code& error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
{
    // do stuff
}

[...]

_acceptor.async_accept(accept_cb); // successfull calls the function above
```

However, I'd like to turn `accept_cb()` into a class function member and am unable to register it with `async_accept()`.

```
void tcp_server::accept_cb(const boost::system::error_code& error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)

[...]

_acceptor.async_accept(boost::bind(&tcp_server::accept_cb, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::placeholders::_1)); // does not compile
_acceptor.async_accept(boost::bind(&tcp_server::accept_cb, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::placeholders::_2)); // does not compile
_acceptor.async_accept(boost::bind(&tcp_server::accept_cb, this, boost::placeholders::_1, boost::placeholders::_2)); // does not compile
```

What is the right syntax to use here?

I learned about `boost::asio::placeholders::error` from an official [boost asio example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) and about `boost::placeholders::_1` and `::_2` from the [boost help page on `bind()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_pointers_to_memb).

Comment: You need to show self-contained code. We don't know the error message. Perhaps the containing member function is marked const etc.

Comment: The question is not "why does my code not compile", it is "which of the options listed is the right way to register a function member as async_accept() callback". If you tell me which one is the *right* one, the question is answered, independently of my code compiling or not.

Comment: All of them, @Multisync. Your whole question hinges on the premise that it doesn't work for you

Comment: Never mind, I just made the self-contained example and realized the problem. Posting an answer soonish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a class function member as callback for `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::async_accept()` (Boost version 1.74) like so:

```
_acceptor.async_accept(std::bind(&tcp_server::accept_cb, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Note the use of stdlib instead of boost.

This is in accordance with the documentation, which states that

- the callback [must be a `MoveAcceptHandler`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload3.html), and that
- adapting non-static class member functions to MoveAcceptHandlers can be done [using `std::bind()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MoveAcceptHandler.html).
- Support of `boost::bind()` is not specifically mentioned and indeed doesn't seem to work as indicated by the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to pass the handler via a lambda expression to `async_accept()` as done in the [c++11 example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) of tcp echo server:

```
_acceptor.async_accept(
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
    {
      accept_cb(ec, std::move(socket));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll wait for a bit if someone posts another answers telling how to have `async_accept()` call that function member directly.

Comment: To do so you have to provide a self-contained code to this stackoverflow post that implements the `tcp_server::accept_cb` method. Then we can analyze your compilation problems.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I get it. By [making your code self-contained](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa69ad9f8fd1cc0c) I finally spotted the issue. The issue is that the handler is the `MoveAcceptHandler` type. Which expects to move the 2nd argument.

Bind expressions do not support move semantics. E.g. `boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp` spells:

```
R operator()(T * p, A1 a1, A2 a2) const
{
    BOOST_MEM_FN_RETURN (p->*f_)(a1, a2);
}
```

You see, that can never work for move arguments. So, indeed, lambda's (or manually coded callables) are your only option *for this particular type of callback*.

### Compare: AsyncReadHandler

Just to show the difference: non-move-only arguments work with all the styles of bind/lambda:

**Live On Compiler Explorer**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(tcp::socket s) : _socket(std::move(s)) {}
    void run() {
        do_read();
    }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        static std::atomic_int _method = 0;

        _buf.clear();

        // package a deferred operation:
        // auto op = async_read(_socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(_buf), asio::deferred);
        auto op = async_read_until(_socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(_buf), "\n", asio::deferred);

        // invoke using any bind technique:
        auto                   selected = (_method++ % 4);
        std::cout << "Using method #" << selected << std::endl;
        switch (selected) {
            case 0: {
                using namespace boost::placeholders;
                return std::move(op)(boost::bind(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
            }
            case 1: {
                namespace ph = asio::placeholders;
                return std::move(op)(boost::bind(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this(), ph::error,
                                                 ph::bytes_transferred));
            }
            case 2: {
                using namespace std::placeholders;
                return std::move(op)(std::bind(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
            }
            case 3: {
                using namespace std::placeholders;
                return std::move(op)([self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t xfr) {
                    self->on_read(ec, xfr);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    void on_read(error_code ec, size_t xfr) {
        if (xfr) {
                _buf.resize(xfr - 1); // eat newline
        }

        std::cout << "Received " << xfr << " bytes " << quoted(_buf) << " from "
                  << _socket.remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

        if (!ec.failed()) {
                do_read();
        }
    }

    std::string _buf;
    tcp::socket _socket;
};

struct Listener {
    Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex) : _acceptor(ex) {}

    void start(uint16_t port) {
        _acceptor.open(tcp::v4());
        _acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        _acceptor.bind({{}, port});
        _acceptor.listen();

        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        using namespace boost::placeholders;
        _acceptor.async_accept(                    //
            make_strand(_acceptor.get_executor()), //
            [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
                std::cout << "Accepted " << s.remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                if (!ec.failed())
                {
                    std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s))->run();
                    do_accept();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Listener lsn{ioc.get_executor()};

    lsn.start(8989);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    ioc.run_for(4s);
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

### Alternative: Not using the `MoveAcceptHandler` version of `async_accept`

There is an older interface - obviously for compatibility with C++03:

Here, again, all the bind methods work:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/269fb46a49d3a803)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(asio::any_io_executor ex) : _socket(ex) {}

    void         run()       { do_read();      } 
    tcp::socket& getSocket() { return _socket; } 

  private:
    void do_read() {
        using namespace boost::placeholders;
        _buf.clear();
        async_read_until(_socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(_buf), "\n",
                         boost::bind(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
    }

    void on_read(error_code ec, size_t xfr) {
        if (xfr) {
                _buf.resize(xfr - 1); // eat newline
        }

        std::cout << "Received " << xfr << " bytes " << quoted(_buf) << " from "
                  << _socket.remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

        if (!ec.failed()) {
                do_read();
        }
    }

    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::string _buf;
};

struct Listener {
    Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex) : _acceptor(ex) {}

    void start(uint16_t port) {
        _acceptor.open(tcp::v4());
        _acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        _acceptor.bind({{}, port});
        _acceptor.listen();

        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        static std::atomic_int _method = 0;

        auto  tmp = std::make_shared<Session>(make_strand(_acceptor.get_executor()));
        auto& s   = tmp->getSocket();
        auto  cb  = &Listener::accept_cb;

        // invoke using any bind technique:
        auto selected = (_method++ % 4);
        std::cout << "Using method #" << selected << std::endl;
        switch (selected) {
            case 0: {
                using namespace boost::placeholders;
                return _acceptor.async_accept(s, boost::bind(cb, this, _1, tmp));
            }
            case 1: {
                namespace ph = asio::placeholders;
                return _acceptor.async_accept(
                    s, boost::bind(cb, this, ph::error, tmp));
            }
            case 2: {
                using namespace std::placeholders;
                return _acceptor.async_accept(s, std::bind(&Listener::accept_cb, this, _1, tmp));
            }
            case 3: {
                using namespace std::placeholders;
                return _acceptor.async_accept(s, [this, tmp](error_code ec) { accept_cb(ec, tmp); });
            }
        }
    }

    void accept_cb(error_code ec, std::shared_ptr<Session> sess) {
        std::cout << "Accepted " << sess->getSocket().remote_endpoint() //
                  << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

        if (!ec.failed()) {
            sess->run();
            do_accept();
        }
    }

    tcp::acceptor _acceptor;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Listener lsn{ioc.get_executor()};

    lsn.start(8989);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    ioc.run_for(4s);
}
```

Prints, on Coliru:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
./a.out& sleep 1
for line in foo bar qux quuz platonic love; do nc 127.0.0.1 8989 -w 1 <<< "$line"; done
wait
```

Output

```
Using method #0
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46730 (Success)
Using method #1
Received 4 bytes "foo" from 127.0.0.1:46730 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46730 (End of file)
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46732 (Success)
Using method #2
Received 4 bytes "bar" from 127.0.0.1:46732 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46732 (End of file)
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46734 (Success)
Using method #3
Received 4 bytes "qux" from 127.0.0.1:46734 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46734 (End of file)
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46736 (Success)
Using method #0
Received 5 bytes "quuz" from 127.0.0.1:46736 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46736 (End of file)
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46738 (Success)
Using method #1
Received 9 bytes "platonic" from 127.0.0.1:46738 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46738 (End of file)
Accepted 127.0.0.1:46740 (Success)
Using method #2
Received 5 bytes "love" from 127.0.0.1:46740 (Success)
Received 0 bytes "" from 127.0.0.1:46740 (End of file)
```

Comment: Added, for completeness, the non-move-aware version of async_accept that will work with all the shown bind methods as well as in C++03 if you need

Comment: Obviously in C++03 `std::bind` and lambdas aren't available - as are several other language features: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e0246baef8f72de